# Male kitten bullying his sister out of food?

Tags: cats, behavior

I have just gotten two cats, and I've never had cats before. My boy (3 months) is  growling? at my girl (4 months). They've always eaten together; with wet food it wasn't a problem, but I'm now putting dry food in the bowl. My boy is acting really aggressive towards the other while eating. I put their food in separate bowls, but my boy is still being a jerk. He eats his food as fast as possible, then goes and tries to take my girl's food. I've tried putting them in other rooms, but my boy doesn't eat until he comes out. I don't know what to do and to be honest, I don't really want to supervise their eating all the time. What should I do?

Comment: Are they both desexed (neutered/spayed)? Does the boy steal wet food or only kibble? What about the girl? You didn't mention anything about her behavior. Can you please add these details to help us answer? (And welcome to cat ownership!)

Comment: How can I teach my kitten not to steal the other kitten's food? https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/how-can-i-teach-my-kitten-not-to-steal-the-other-kittens-food?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing with my cats, also a boy and a girl. What I ended up doing was putting the feeding bowl in a separate room with my girl and the door closed so the boy couldn't get in.

After my queen had finished eating, I would put out food normally.

Competition is normal, however, and this is still going on between them now that they are 5 years old. My female has accepted this and waits with eating until my male cat has finished.

Sometimes though, when she's really hungry, I have noticed her pushing the male out of the way to eat, and at other times, there's growling and some hissing, but never fighting.

As some have already suggested, spaying and neutering is really necessary and will improve behaviour.